# Find an expression equalling 69 using the digits 1 9 9 2 in order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A friend gave me a puzzle to find an expression for each of the integers $1$ to $100$ using the digits $1, 9, 9, 2$ such that they appear in that exact order. You're allowed any combination of the four basic operations, brackets, square roots, the factorial, exponentiation and also you can put digits together, e.g. we could have $23=19+(\sqrt{9})!-2$. I've managed every number relatively quickly except $69$ which I've been stuck on for ages and it's infuriating! Any ideas?

Edit: Apologies for my unclear explanation. You're only allowed to put the original digits together in the equation. The equation must make sense as a normal equation so you can't do things like combine $1$ with $\sqrt{9}$ to get $13$ because this can't be written down in a way which makes sense as a normal equation.

Also you aren't allowed to just use powers, unless you're using one of the four digits themselves, e.g. $2=1+(9/9)^2$ is okay because we've used the $2$ as a power but $69=(1-9)^2+\sqrt{9}+2$ isn't because there's now a superfluous $2$.

Comment: How did you get 46

Comment: $(-1+9).(\sqrt{9})!-2$

Answer (score 0):

Since we can put digits together, one solution might be

$1+ ((\sqrt{9})!)((\sqrt{9})!) +2$

One expression which does not keep the exact order is

$9*9-12$ or $((\sqrt{9})!)((\sqrt{9}+1) +2$

Comment: No, this violates the edit about the concatenation about digits.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

$$(1-9)^2+\sqrt{9}+2.$$

Comment: Unfortunately you're not allowed squares only square roots.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets the "makes sense as a normal equation" condition, but if we can apply the square root operator an infinite number of times we have:

$$69 = 71-2 = \sqrt{5041} - 2 = \sqrt{1 + 7!} - 2 = \sqrt{1 +(3!+1)!}-2$$

$$= \sqrt{1 + \Big((\sqrt9)! + 1\Big)!}-2 = \sqrt{1 + \Bigg((\sqrt9)! + \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{ \cdots9}}}\Bigg)!}-2$$

where the dots indicate an infinite sequence of nested square roots.  Note that:

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{ \cdots9}}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(9^{(1/2)^n}\Big) = 1$$

Comment: Such contests occasionally allow bracket=floor function. Meaning that in place of that limit you can use $\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{9}}\rfloor=1$. Not sure?

Comment: No, the "infinite number of times of a square root" does not follow, as it was explained byJyrki Lahtonen, gives it for the floor function.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment, therefore I am posting this as an answer and delete it later.

$(\sqrt{9})!9 = 69$, since $(\sqrt{9})!=6$, since you said, it is allowed to put digits together.

Getting rid of the 1 is not a problem $1\cdot n=n$.
But still I need to get rid of the 2.

edit: 
$1 + \underbrace{(\sqrt{9})! (\sqrt{9})!}_{=66} + 2 = 69$

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, you're only allowed to put the original digits together, i.e. it has to make sense as an equation to someone viewing it unfamiliar with the puzzle. Although if we do allow that you could get $6$ by doing $1*(\sqrt{9})!$ and $9$ by $\sqrt{9^2}$ and put them together to get $69$.

Comment: It is standard practice, at the times when allowing concatenation, that it only mean the placement of immediate individual digits to form two-digit or longer numbers.  Or, if in addition that decimal points are used, decimal number can be created such as .12, 1.2, 12.3, 12.34, etc.

Answer (score -1):

How about $\ \ \ \ $ $$-1+9!!!-92$$
or

$$(1+\sqrt{9})!+9\div.2$$

Comment: No multifactorials only the usual one sorry.

Comment: Isn't 9!!! huge, how is this supposed to be 69

Comment: $!!!$ can mean the triple factorial, i.e. multiply every third number so $9!!!=9.6.3$

Comment: No decimal points sorry! Although very ingenious.